# GmailApp for specific email or forced to use logged in email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

GmailApp.search is great for pulling emails but what if I want to access a specific Gmail account logged in or not logged in is this possible with GmailApp or maybe some other method I am unaware of? Or am I forced to use the email address the user is logged in?

Comment: Hey @CodeCamper which solution did you eventually go for? I'd  love to hear. Thanks!

Comment: @carlesgg97 I haven't thoroughly tested it yet but I suspect the easiest way is to install a trigger with the clock looking symbol in the script editor, whoever installs the trigger will always be running the "GmailApp"

Comment: sounds reasonable! However the end user will have to trust your script haha. It just came to my mind that if you are using GSuite, and you plan on executing the script on behalf of users of your domain, you can use domain-wide delegation to accomplish that

Answer (score 1):

Due to security and privacy concerns, `GmailApp` service as well as the rest of the services provided by Google Apps Script and Google REST APIs can only access the logged-in user's data. In order to access another user's data, he/she will have to **manually** log in using the [oAuth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). As an option, you may create a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that the end-user would connect to and manually authorize your application to be run using his/her data.

Comment: What about [delegates](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350)? They already have access to the other address through their own login.